# Valorant Install Size

Tags: valorant

How many GB does Valorant need for installation?

Google claims 7.3GB but that appears to be the download size, not the install size.

On https://playvalorant.com/en-us/specs/ install size is not stated.

Answer (score 5):

As of January 2021, the install size officially is 12.2GB:

[image: Setup UI]

With 142MB download size for the installer:

[image: installer setup]

And 6GB main download:

[image: main download]

The total installed file size is **13.3 GB**

```
270M    Riot Client\
13G     VALORANT\
```

This is likely to increase over time.

Answer (score 3):

According to [PrimaGames](https://primagames.com/tips/valorant-download-size-install-PC):

> At first, you’ll simply download the install client which is around 65 MB. From there you’ll need to download Riot Vanguard, which is a 3.6 GB anti-cheat system that every player must have before they can play. Once you’ve gotten that squared away, you’ll be able to install the rest of the Valorant files onto your PC, which will bring you to a grand total of somewhere between 7-8 GB.

3.6 GB for an anti-cheat application seems a little steep to me, and [other](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/valorant-specs-required-minimum-recommended-high-end-7031) [sources](https://www.sportskeeda.com/esports/valorant-download-size-pc-what-game-file-size) indeed mention those 3.6 GB are actually the size of the download, making the 7.3 ("7-8") GB the actual installation size.

[GameRevolution](https://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/653811-valorant-install-size-gb-download), in an article posted around a month later than the others linked to here, mentions slightly higher numbers:

> **The total download size for Valorant is just over 4.1 GB**. However, the game’s file size will more than double after installation. In total, **you will need 9 GB of free space on your hard drive** to install and play Valorant.

Note that over time updates/patches will likely increase the amount of space necessary.

Answer (score 2):

On my computer, the Valorant folder in `C:\Riot Games\Valorant` is 22.6 GB. It could vary, but is likely to stay around that number.

Answer (score 1):

As @Joachim stated over time updates/patches will likely increase the amount of space necessary. I suggest at least having 20 GB free on your drive just to be safe but 15 should be enough.